# How to store documents encrypted

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, document

I am writing a web application that will store documents server-side. Now I am looking for the best way to do the document storing part.

Directly in file system is no option, because the user should not have direct access to them.
So I have some options in mind and want to here your opinion or experience or ideas for other possible ways.

1. Store them in some password protected container format like zip, and only store container and document name in table. Split archives after a size limit.
2. Store them as BLOB inside MySQL in a separate table.
3. Store them in a MySQL archive engine table.
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/archive-storage-engine.html
4. Use MongoDB and GridFS to store the data.

Requirements:

- The user has no direct access to the files.
- The files must always be consistent.
- Storing files in the table should not slow down the rest of the application.

If I use a DB, I will store the data in a separate table and search over a second table with some meta data fields.

Comment: All your options are overkill, store files as files. If a file is on the server it doesn't mean any user can access it.

Comment: @slash197 in some cases, the filesystem may be volatile and external storage in a database may be necessary. But assuming that the filesystem has guaranteed stability, you are correct.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I agree but the only reason OP mentioned here not to use file system is user access

Comment: Just store outside root.  Serve via script.  Problem solved

Comment: The application can run on a root webserver. But also on the customers own hardware as an inhouse hosted application. Some CEOs dont like all data in the cloud :) And in this case some user can get access to the filesystem. Also in the law text, the filesystem is exclusive excluded. So if the system should be law conform it is not an option. I talk about a document managment system. Where you scan all your company papers into.